# Korganizer time format

Tags: kubuntu, korganizer

How to force Korganizer to use 24 hour clock format.
I set Region to Poland.
I set Translations Preferred Languages to American English.
Time on the panel is in 24h format but in Korganizer it's 12h.

Answer (score 0):

In Korganizer,
Select the menu **Settings**
select **Configure Date & Time**
in the side panel select **Formats**
in the **Time** dropdown menu select **Polska - polski(pl_PL)**
click **OK**

A small notification box will appear telling you that *Your changes will take effect the next time you login*.

Logout and login.
The time bar on the left of the calendar will show in 24.00 format.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open: Set Time Format
2. In the side panel select Formats
3. In the Time dropdown menu select "Default C"
4. Click OK

([Source](https://cubiclenate.com/blatherings/kderegionalsettingsformat/))